# Can I calculate $E(X^2)$ if I know that $X$~$B(1, \frac{1}{3})$ (binomial distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, binomial-distribution

If I know that I have $X$~$B(1, \frac{1}{3})$ (binomial distribution),

Can I calculate (the expectancy) $E(X^2)$ ?

(That's a part of a question, that if I can calculate it, it will make the question faster).

An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
EX^2 = 0^2 \times \frac{2}{3} + 1^2 \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Generally, you can observe that in your case $EX^k = \frac{1}{3}$, for all $k > 0$, as 
$$
EX^k =  0^k \times\frac{2}{3} + 1^k \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}. 
$$

Comment: can you perhaps explain why?

Comment: @sheldonzy In general if $X$ is a discrete random variable then $\mathbb Ef(X)=\sum_if(i)P(X=i)$. This is applied here.

Comment: @drhab Right, but why the $0^k \cdot \frac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: @sheldonzy Here $f(x)=x^k$ so that $\mathbb EX^k=Ef(X)=f(0)P(X=0)+f(1)P(X=1)=0^k\cdot\frac23+1^k\cdot\frac13$

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $X$~$B(n,p)$ then $E(X)=np$ and $V(X)=npq$ where $q=1-p$. And $$E(X^2)=E(X)^2+V(X) \tag{1}$$

You can calculate the desired value from $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ so that $X^2=X$.